# Can I request Apple to expedite the approval of a new version of my app to rectify a critical bug

Tags: ios-appstore, app-store-connect

If my app is live and users are facing a critical issue, can I upload another build and ask Apple to make it live within a day or two?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes; there's a feature called [Expedited app review](https://developer.apple.com/support/app-review/) precisely for these cases. From my personal experience, it takes usually about 24 hours to complete, but that's no guarantee.

From the linked page:

> ### Expedited App Review
>
> If you face extenuating circumstances, you can request the review of your app to be expedited. These circumstances include fixing a critical bug in your app on the App Store or releasing your app to coincide with an event you are directly associated with.
>
> #### Urgent Bug Fix
>
> If you've submitted an update to fix a critical bug in your app on the App Store and you are requesting an expedited review, be sure to include the steps to reproduce the bug on the current version of your app.
>
> #### Time-Sensitive Event
>
> For apps associated with an event, we recommend you plan and schedule the release of your app in iTunes Connect. However, if your app is still in review and the launch of your event is quickly approaching, you can request to have your app review expedited. When submitting your request, it's important to include the event, date of the event, and your app's association with the event.
>
> Please Note: Expedited reviews are granted on a limited basis and we cannot guarantee that every request will be expedited.

It's a (partly) automated process, you can just sign in and [request one](https://developer.apple.com/contact/app-store/?topic=expedite) on the Developer Portal.

Comment: Right. The dirty little secret of the app store is, the (handful) of actually high selling apps are treated in a totally different way by totally different teams. If you're on a game or something that's doing well, or for any major name brand, service is personalized and you never have to wait anyway.  For the masses, just as explained here there is an expedited process, but, it takes usually a day or two anyway.

Comment: @Fattie I know of more than an handful of indie developers and small time outfits that have had expedited reviews in a matter of hours. I’ve also known the normal review process to be that fast as well. My experience hasn’t been as you describe - but I also can’t say what a large organization receives in terms of service and preferential treatment.

Comment: At any rate, it's better than it was before. I remember planning two weeks for an app release three years ago - anything faster was a bonus.

Comment: @bmike - fair enough, indeed in general it is simply much faster than in the "old days".  I think the bottom line for the OP is that it takes "24-48 hrs" for the expedited review.

Comment: Yeah. When one of my app was in top 10, anything I updated was approved in few hours back then.